# How to parsing array inside array in the same json file?

Tags: json, jq

### How to parsing an array inside the array in the same JSON file?

This is the JSON file:

```
{
  "customers": [
    {
      "id": 268467952,
      "firstName": "And",
      "lastName": "Little",
      "gender": "Unknown",
      "photoType": "default",
      "photoUrl": "https://d33v4339jhl8k0.cloudfront.net/customer-avatar/02.png",
      "createdAt": "2019-07-10T12:37:42Z",
      "updatedAt": "2019-07-10T12:37:41Z",
      "background": "",
      "_embedded": {
        "emails": [
          {
            "id": 360891952,
            "value": "info@look.co.uk",
            "type": "work"
          }
        ]}
}]}
```

I would like to get output like this:

```
{
  "id": 268467952,
  "id": 360891952,
  "value": "info@thatweblook.co.uk",
  "type": "work"
}
```

I have tried to run this command but got null in the columns emails.id, emails.value, emails.type:

```
jq '

{customers: .customers[], _embedded: ._embedded }
| if ._embedded == null then

{id: .customers .id, idemail: null, valueemail: null, typeemail: null}
else

{id: .customers .id, id: ._embedded .emails[] .id, value: ._embedded .emails[] .value,  type: ._embedded .emails[] .type }
end'  /home/help-scout/only-cust/file.json > //home/help-scout/only-cust-read/file-cust-read.json
```

From this code I'm getting null in the emails columns:

```
{
  "id": 268467952,
  "idemail": null,
  "valueemail": null,
  "typeemail": null
}
```

Pls your assistance:)
Thanks!

Comment: The expected output that is shown has "info@thatweblook.co.uk", which does not appear in the input that is shown.  Please reconcile.

Answer (score 0):

Although the expected output as shown in the question is technically valid JSON, the duplication of keys is inadvisable for various reasons.  So let's assume at least for now that the following output would be acceptable:

```
{
  "customerid": 268467952,
  "id": 360891952,
  "value": "info@look.co.uk",
  "type": "work"
}
```

This can be generated by the jq filter:

```
.customers[] | {customerid: .id} + ._embedded.emails[]
```

Now if you really want the inadvisable duplication of keys, you can run the output produced by jq through some text-processing tool like sed or awk.